# Estimate for the first eigenvalue of the Laplacian

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, laplacian

I was studying the paper of S. T. Yau - Seminar on Differential Geometry - and there asks if the first eigenvalue is equal to $ n $, if we have a embedded oriented Riemannian manifold and closed dimension $ n $ in the unit sphere Euclidean $ \mathbb{S}^{n + 1}$. It is well known that Choi-Wang gave an answer, even if partial to this conjecture, showing that the first eigenvalue is $\lambda \geq \frac{n}{2}$.

Thus, I wonder if there is a counter example that proves to be false the question of Yau, if we have in place of the embedded, an immersion? I confess I've tried enough to find this possible counter example, if it can be called that, for this conjecture. Muto has shown that it is true for any class of isoparametric hypersurfaces as well as homogeneous hypersurfaces.

Already, thank you.

Comment: Presumably you mean minimal hypersurface? If so, it's false for immersed minimal hypersurfaces: consider the Clifford torus in $S^3$. Cyclic covers of this will be immersed with arbitrarily small first eigenvalue.